# The Mahler measure of a binary form and the natural action of a matrix ring

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $F(x,y) = a_0 \prod_{i=1}^d(x-\alpha_iy)$ be a binary form of degree $d \geq 2$ and nonzero discriminant $D(F)$. Define the Mahler measure $M(F)$ of $F$ by

$$M(F) = \left|a_0\right| \prod\limits_{i=1}^d\max\{1,|\alpha_i|\}.$$

Further, for any matrix

$$A = \left(\begin{matrix}a & b\\c & d\end{matrix}\right),$$

whose entries are integers, define

$$F_A(x,y) = F(ax + by, cx + dy)$$

and let

$$
M_0(F) = \inf\limits_{A \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)}\{M(F_A)\}.
$$

Let $B$ be a matrix with integer entries such that $|\det(B)| > 1$. I wonder if there exist a good upper bound or a lower bound on

$$M_0(F_B) = \inf\limits_{A \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)}\{M(F_{BA})\},$$

which possibly involve $\det(B), M_0(F)$ or $D(F)$.

Comment: I think you want $|a_0|$ in your definition of $M(F)$.